# How to change inactive color on bottom navigation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, navigation

I can't change inactive color on my bottom navigation

[image]

and this my xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/home_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:title="Home"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/setting_item"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"
    android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:title="Setting"
    />
```

and this my java

```
bottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bottom_tabs));
bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#FFFFFE");
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 98):

If you are using the BottomNavigationView, the solution could be easy.
You just need to create a selector as a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html), then assign the selector to the "itemIconTint" attribute of the BottomNavigationView.

For example:

Create file inside drawable

**bottom_nav_icon_color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/InactiveBottomNavIconColor" />
</selector>
```

**BotttomNavigationview.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavMainMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/BottomNavBarColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

Comment: @color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector is not correct. this file is drawable!

Comment: @BoshRa put it in `res/color` instead of `res/drawable` then you'll be able to reference it with `@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector`

Comment: should be accepted as the answer.  i have spent hours trying to get this working, and this solution is the first xml solution that has worked for me.

Comment: This is not working, the inactive can't be seen for me

Comment: This does not work either for me... android has some many issues with themes.  They never got it right and now its a hodge-podge of values depending on material design lib or appcompat...ugh.  I spend more time trying to fix little things like this coloring the F'ing icons in a bottomNavBar

Answer (score 12):

[Chrislis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335159/2212770) is a good start. However I like to solve this problem via styling and theming. I also used the new material [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView) for this example.

**Create a new file under the color folder, for example: `bottom_nav_item_color.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/item_color_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/item_color_inactive"/>
</selector>
```

**Add this line to your base theme located in `themes.xml`**

```
<item name="bottomNavigationStyle">@style/BottomNavigationViewStyle</item>
```

**Add this code to `styles.xml`**

```
<style name="BottomNavigationViewStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
    <item name="android:background">@color/my_background_color</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/bottom_nav_item_color</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@color/bottom_nav_item_color</item>
</style>
```

Now the BottomNavigationView should be styled correctly

**Example layout file**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Comment: I love the abstraction theming offers.

Answer (score 3):

I've sligthly edited @Wirling answer to match Android Studio 4.2 Canary 16.

You just have to define your active/inactive colors under the color folder, for example `bottom_nav_item.color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/item_color_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/item_color_inactive"/>
</selector>
```

Then, in your BottomNavigationView just use previous created selector like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

So its super simple. You have to create your selector in new .xml file and then use it for your BottomNavigationView in

```
 app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
 app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_item_color"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bottom Navigation select text and icon Color**
first bottom navigation home layout activity

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_color_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/home_menu">

</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

**then selector file create in drawable**
**item_color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/bottomBarItemColor" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:color="@color/colorDivider" android:state_selected="false" />
```

**then create text selected color xml file in drawable**
**text_color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/white" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:color="@color/colorDivider" android:state_selected="false" />
```

**then add style on theme xml**

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.BottomNavView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorDivider</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorDivider</item>
</style>
```

**then create home menu xml file in res directory**

**home_menu.xml add in menu directory**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_live_date"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector"
    android:title="Live Data"
    android:enabled="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_house_details"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector"
    android:title="House Details"
    android:enabled="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_attendance"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector"
    android:title="Attendance"
    android:enabled="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_emp_details"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_selector"
    android:title="Emp Details"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

**End Thank you so much**

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.RunnerApp" 

parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    
<!-- Primary brand color. -->

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item  
<!-- Secondary brand color. -->
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item> 
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item> 
<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>

<!-- Status bar color. --> 
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">? 
attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

In most of the case...developer change there theme to NoActionBar
But instead of
**Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar**
They change it into
**Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar**
That causes all these colour issues

Navigation component use material design so keep this point in mind

Answer (score -3):

Try below code. Hope its helpful!!!

```
mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
        mBottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundResource(R.color.navigationColor);
        mBottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
```

Comment: Try adding some context to your code to help future readers better understand its meaning.